# Socket.io keeps losing connection to the MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I have a program using socket.io and MySQL about every 9-10 hours the program is running it will randomly lose connection to the MySQL database and cause the whole program to shut down here is what the error looks like

The error printed to the console.

[image: The error printed to the console]

So basically I'm here asking for you to help me decide #1 Is this a problem in the code or with the MySQL server and #2 What should I do to fix this problem

Comment: Please put the text of any errors into the body of the question. You also need, at the very least, describe how the program and the server are located on the network they share, and probably all the OS details. You might also check the SQL server debug logs.

Comment: Any timeouts set on the mysql server?

Comment: It happens with MySQL server when you keep the connection open too long.  Try pooling  https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections